# change calendar after every two months in php

Tags: php, date

I have a php code as shown below in which I am trying to change calendar after every two months.

What I am trying to achieve on the webapge is:

**(a)** When the current month is **January or February**, it should display all dates for **January and February** (**in readonly mode**). 
 
**(b)** When the current month is **March or April**, it should display all dates for **March and April** (**in readonly mode**).
**(c)** And so on..

The sequence should be January February, March April, May June, July August, September October, November December. (technically the calendar change should happen after every 2 months).

I am also attaching the screenshot in order to make things clear. (I want my webpage to look exactly as it is when the current month is March or April) and if current month is May or June then it should show all dates for those two months only.

[image]

**Php code:**

This is what I have tried but I think more need to be done. I have added `foreach` loop for **Code A** and **Code B** because it will loop through dates for the month.

The reason why I have added two codes **(Code A and Code B**) so that one code **(Code A)** loop through odd month and another code **(Code B)** loop through even month but I am not sure if that is the way I should implement it.

```
$odd_months = array('January', 'March', 'May', 'July ', 'September', 'November',);
$current = date('F');
```

**Code A:**

```
<div class="abc-xyz">
<?php foreach ($period as $date) { ?>
    <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
        <input type="date" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); ?>">
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Code B:**

```
<div class="abc-xyz">
<?php foreach ($period as $date) { ?>
    <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
        <input type="date" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); ?>">
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a try. Pass it the number of a month and it should do the rest.

```
<?php

function buildDateSelection($month) {
    # array will hold our months
    $months = array();

    # determine whether we have an odd or even month number    
    if($month % 2 == 0) {
        # even month is always the second
        # so add the one before $month and $month itself
        $months[] = str_pad(($month - 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        # for odd ones add $month and $month + 1
        $months[] = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $months[] = str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them
    $year = date('Y');

    foreach($months as $month) {
        # create timestamp for the first of a month
        # then get number of days for that month
        $numberOfDays = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

        # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
        for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDays; $i++) {
            $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                <input type="date" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
            </div>';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

?>
```

Example use cases:

```
<?php 
    # specific month
    echo buildDateSelection(4);

    # get the current month
    echo buildDateSelection(date('n'));
?>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a typo, needs to be the passed $month to check that number. Fixed it.

Comment: Tested it locally, works fine. Also added example calls.

Comment: My apologies for the epic delay in reply. I have marked your answer accept. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758018/display-html-li-elements-column-wise-under-their-alphabets-in-php). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: Glad it could help you.

Comment: hey, I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691611/how-to-allow-the-2nd-user-to-take-over-when-the-1st-user-is-logged-in). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="abc-xyz"> <?php 
   $year = date('Y');
   $month = date('n');

   for($i = $month; $i <= $month+1; $i++) {
      $d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $i, $year);
      for($j = 1; $j <= $d; $j++){ ?>
         <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
            <input type="datetime" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $year.'-'.$i.'-'.$j; ?>">
         </div> <?php 
      }
   } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The logic seems fine to me. I ran your code in my codebase and this is what I am getting https://imgur.com/oGvvd46 (No date values are coming)

Comment: This is what I am getting on doing inspect for a particular row: `<input type="date" readonly="readonly" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date_current_month[]" value="2020-1-1">`

Comment: Although, it showing values now but I think you didn't get my question. Currently, it should be printing all dates for March and April. In your code, It is printing dates of January.

Comment: There is a bug in this logic. I am explaining my question again. When its January or February -> It should display all dates for January and February. When its March or April -> It should display all dates for March and April. (technically the calendar change should happen after every 2 months)

Comment: On the webpage currently it should be displaying all dates for March and April.

Comment: Whats happening with your code is when its January its displaying all dates for January and February. When its February, its displaying all dates for February and March. 
When its March, its displaying all dates for March and April. When its April, its displaying all dates for April and May.

Comment: Let me know if i make sense with my question.