# display html li elements column-wise under their alphabets in php

Tags: php, foreach, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I have a php code as shown below which **displays list of items (listings)** under their alphabets column-wise (show in the fiddle below).

**php code:**

```
if ( is_array( $beta_lists ) && ! empty( $beta_lists ) ) :
    $before_title_character  = '';
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($beta_lists); echo "</pre>";   // Line A
    ?>
    <ul id="programs-list" class="programs-list js-list-active">
        <?php foreach ( $beta_lists as $title => $permalink ) :
            $character_title=substr(transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII;', $title),0,1);
             ?>
            <li class="shows-list__letter">
                <?php if ( $character_title !== $before_title_character ) : $before_title_character = $character_title; ?>
                    <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?php echo esc_html( $character_title ) ?></h1>
                <?php  endif; ?>
                 <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"> <h2 class="shows-list__title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>
                 </a>
            </li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried my best to replicate the DOM in the fiddle coming through php.  https://jsfiddle.net/s4x1zf7L/3/ The CSS present in the fiddle is exactly what I am using currently.

**Problem Statement:**

Although list is displaying column-wise under their alphabets, the issue in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4x1zf7L/3/) is that,

**1.** The 2nd column **starts will a listing not with an alphabet**. (In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4x1zf7L/3/), **Bachelor** listing starts from another column. It should be in 1st column only)

**2.** Adding a new list under alphabets often results another list being orphaned at the top of the 2nd column.

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that  in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4x1zf7L/3/) **2 alphabets should be in one column** and **2 alphabets in another** without 
any list being orphaned in the 2nd column.

In case if we add 7 (odd) number of alphabets then 4 alphabets should be in left column and 3 alphabets should be in right column without any list being orphaned in the 2nd column.

(**The 2nd column should always start with an alphabet with the lists below it.)**

**Line A** in the php code above prints the following array:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => http://www.abc.mno/apple/
    [Ball] => http://www.abc.mno/ball/
    [Builders] => http://www.abc.mno/builders/
    [Bowling] => http://www.abc.mno/bowling/
    [Batting] => http://www.abc.mno/batting/
    [Bone] => http://www.abc.mno/bone/
    [Bachelor] => http://www.abc.mno/bachelor/
    [Correct] => http://www.abc.mno/correct/
    [Campaign] => http://www.abc.mno/compain/
    [Direct] => http://www.abc.mno/direct/
    [Degree] => http://www.abc.mno/degree/
)
```

The number of elements in the array can change depending upon the values presen

**This is what I have tried:**

I tried avoiding orphanage of elements using css by adding margin in the 2nd column but everytime when new list gets added, I have to modify the css values which I believe 
is not a long term solution.

**Note:** The DOM is not in my control. It's only the php which is in my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the multiples `<li>` between the same letter elements.
This is your code:

```
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">B</h1>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.abc.mno/ball/">
     <h2 class="shows-list__title">Ball</h2>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.abc.mno/builders/">
     <h2 class="shows-list__title">Builders</h2>
  </a>
</li>
...
```

This is how it should be:

```
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">B</h1>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.abc.mno/ball/">
     <h2 class="shows-list__title">Ball</h2>
  </a>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.abc.mno/builders/">
     <h2 class="shows-list__title">Builders</h2>
  </a>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://www.abc.mno/bowling/">
     <h2 class="shows-list__title">Bowling</h2>
  </a>
 ....
```

and then add this to avoid page break between the elements:

```
.shows-list__letter {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Result here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ndajurv/

**update**

In your PHP change

```
<li class="shows-list__letter">
    <?php if ( $character_title !== $before_title_character ) : $before_title_character = $character_title; ?>
        <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?php echo esc_html( $character_title ) ?></h1>
    <?php  endif; ?>
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>">
        <h2 class="shows-list__title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>
    </a>
</li>
```

with

```
<?php if ( $character_title !== $before_title_character ) : ?>
    <li class="shows-list__letter">
        <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title"><?php echo esc_html( $character_title ) ?></h1>
<?php  endif; ?>
        <a class="shows-list__link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>">
            <h2 class="shows-list__title"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>
        </a>
<?php if ( $character_title !== $before_title_character ) : 
        $before_title_character = $character_title; ?>
    </li>
<?php  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, the DOM is not in my control. Its the php which is in my control. The DOM is creating through php. I am wondering if you can give me a hint what changes I need to make in the php code in order to achieve that.

Comment: Put the `<li ..>` and `</li>` inside some `if`. If the letter is the same (A, B, C) then you don't create a new `<li>` element. When the letter changes, then you create it.

Comment: I am wondering if I can put the  `if ( $character_title !== $before_title_character ) : $before_title_character = $character_title;` on starting of  `<li>` .

Comment: It's possible. Try it and then check the result. The final HTML is the one I put in the answer.

Comment: I tried, it's just pulling only one list under alphabet.Not sure why this is happening. There are multiple items under alphabet.

Comment: Updated to fix your problem

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem. My apologies if I didn't explain my question properly. What I want to achieve is that there should be no orphan list/element in the 2nd column. 2nd Column should always start with an alphabet and then the list below that.

Comment: Let's say if there are 4 alphabets then there should 2 alphabets on the left hand side and 2 alphabets on the right side. For odd number of alphabets (if its 7 let us suppose), there should be always 4 alphabets on the left hand side and 3 on the right hand side.

Comment: I am wondering if I have explained my question properly or if you need more information.